# Nexys2 VGA pattern

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I am running Nexys2-1200 board (with a spartan3).It comes with a preloaded configuration that displays a VGA test pattern, that works fine.

I'd be curious to have the complete VHDL code of this pattern. I can't find it on Digilent website...

Anyone ?

Comment: Where have you looked.  What source code/ reference designs have you found?

Comment: Sorry yes : site is [here](http://www.digilentinc.com/Products/Detail.cfm?Prod=NEXYS2) . But the VGA reference is not the demo pre-loaded on the board.

Comment: When you say vga reference are you referring to "DSD-0000241 VGA controller reference design"?  Can you describe what test pattern the demo displays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking really quick at the site for the nexys2 board:
http://www.digilentinc.com/Products/Detail.cfm?Prod=NEXYS2

I see this "Nexys2 Board verification Project - (for 1200K boards)" entry in the support documents section.  I would guess that this contains the source for the design that comes with the board.  In fact when I look into that zip file I see source and documentation for a  vga demo.

The general advice would be to carefully look at all of the reference designs and projects that come with a board and make sure the feature you are looking for is not rolled in with another project.

Comment: Precisely, that is not the demo. That is my initial question.

Comment: Please provide more detail on what the demo is.  What test pattern is it displaying.  Also describe the vga demo/test pattern that you found.